# Como funciona uma validação de autenticação com Angular + PHP

Tags: php, html, angular

Sou iniciante em angular (versão acima da 2) estou estudando a comunicação do angular com o PHP, na parte de httpClient (do rxjs) pra fazer o GET, POST, PUT e DELETE entendi bem. Minha dúvida é como funciona isso para fazer um login? 
Pelo que entendi até o momento é assim:

Tenho um formulário envio o login e senha via POST com angular, ai no PHP eu valido isso no MySql e se o login e senha estiverem certos gero um token no PHP, armazeno esse token em uma session PHP e envio ele para armazenar também na session storage do navegador, depois sempre fico comparando o token do session storage com o token lá da session PHP e assim saberei se o usr já está logado.

O funcionamento seria assim mesmo? Gostaria de entender melhor essa parte.

Comment: Sim, basicamente é isso, existem ja bibliotecas que funcionam com varios tratamentos de dados erros e comparações de tokens, uma delas é o JWT token, de uma olhada https://dev.to/robdwaller/how-to-create-a-json-web-token-using-php-3gml

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda, só fique com dúvida pq se fala muito em não usar session no lado do servidor ao trabalhar com tokens.  As outras formas de armazenar os tokens (lado servidor), além das sessions, seriam: armazenar em banco de dados ou salvar em arquivos txt. Penso que armazenando em session o consumo de memoria é maior, não seria melhor salvar temporariamente em um banco de dados ou arquivo txt?  Existe alguma forma de validar o token sem armazena-lo em algum lugar, como por ex: uma função genérica capaz de validar as chaves de cada usuário como um todo e não apenas a Signature?